# Yii2 Confirm Password not working

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app, yii2-user, yii2-validation

I am trying to build a signup form, it works fine when I dont use repeat password, it saves to the model, but when I use my repeat password it just does'nt let me save them in the database. My code is below.

**SimUser.php file**

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['user_email', 'user_password_hash','company_id','user_fname', 'user_lname','agree'], 'required'],
            ['agree','required','requiredValue' => 1, 'message' => ''],
            ['user_password_hash_repeat', 'compare','compareAttribute' => 'user_password_hash','message' => 'Password don\'t match'],
            [['agree'],'safe'],
            [['user_password_hash_repeat'],'safe'],
            [['user_company', 'user_suspended', 'user_deleted'], 'integer'],
            [['user_created'], 'safe'],
            [['user_email'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['user_password_hash'], 'string', 'max' => 72],
            [['user_fname', 'user_lname'], 'string', 'max' => 45],
            [['user_auth_key'], 'string', 'max' => 32],
            [['user_access_token'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
        ];
    }
```

My controller action: **site/signup**

```
 public function actionSignup()
    {
        $company = new Company(); 
        $company->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
        $company->save();


        $model = new SimUser();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $model->setPassword($model->user_password_hash);
            $model->generateAuthKey();
            $model->company_id =  $company->company_id;
            //var_dump($model); exit();
            $model->save();
            $model = new LoginForm();
            return $this->render('login',[
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
        return $this->render('signup', [
            'model' => $model,
            'company' => $company,
        ]);
    }
```

Here I am saving the comany name in the company model and the others in the user table.

My views file: **signup.php**

```
<h1>Sign Up</h1> 
                <?= $form->field($model, 'user_fname')->textInput(['placeholder'=>'First Name*','class'=>'form-control col-lg-4'])->label(false);?>
                <?= $form->field($model, 'user_lname')->textInput(['placeholder'=>'Last Name*','class'=>'form-control col-lg-4'])->label(false); ?>
                <?= $form->field($model,'user_email')->textInput(['placeholder'=>'Email*','class'=>'form-control col-lg-4'])->label(false); ?>
                <?= $form->field($model, 'user_password_hash')->passwordInput(['placeholder'=>'Password'])->label(false); ?>
                <?= $form->field($model, 'user_password_hash_repeat')->passwordInput(['placeholder'=>'Confirm Password*','class'=>'form-control col-lg-4'])->label(false); ?>
                <?= $form->field($company, 'company_name')->textInput(['placeholder'=>'Company Name*','class'=>'form-control col-lg-4'])->label(false); ?>
                <?php echo $form->field($model, 'agree')->checkbox(); ?>
                <div class="form-group"> 
                    <?= Html::submitButton('Sign Up', ['class' => 'pull-left padding-0 btn btn-success', 'name' => 'signup-button']) ?>
                </div>
```

The error message for the company doesn't go, it is always there.. attached output as image [image: click here]
Can anyone of you help me solve this issue? Thanks in advance!!

**Company.php**
   */

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['company_name'], 'required'],
        [['company_name'], 'string', 'max' => 75],
    ];
}
```

Comment: provide `Company` model

Comment: Added compny model to my post @DoubleH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the controller have saved Company in the beginnig itself. So everytime, I load the page It is saving before I could submit it. Hence the error remains as it is.

Code to be changed:

```
$company = new Company(); 
        $model = new SimUser(['scenario' => SimUser::SCENARIO_REGISTER]);
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $company->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

            $company->save();

            $model->setPassword($model->user_password_hash);
            $model->generateAuthKey();
            $model->company_id =  $company->company_id;            
            $model->save();
```

So 1 issue has been solved.. Unable to solve the confirm password issue! Would be helpful if someone can post what the mistake is?